# What's the Differences between Equals method and == operator in NHibernate Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate, equals

When I used the following code:

`session.Query<Url>().Where(ur => ur.QueryString == url.QueryString)`

I found my results, but when I tried the same with .Equals, didn't. Why? The Equals() method is the default one, no overrides.

What's the difference between these LINQ queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest difference is that they are different "functions". `public static bool operator == (Object other)` and `public bool Equals(Object other)` can be independently defined.

However, even when they do the same thing (or one calls the other), the fact that they are different calls still means something to a Linq provider. The upshot is that the NHibernate queryable provider, which "translates" the expression tree you create using a Linq query or method chain, might treat the two differently. It might correctly parse `.Where(ur => ur.QueryString == url.QueryString)` into `WHERE ur.QueryString = 'MyUrlQueryStringValue'`, but `.Where(ur => ur.QueryString.Equals(url.QueryString))` might be ignored as unusable, or return an error, or be parsed into `WHERE 0`.

Comment: The .Equals() works in others cenarios, the problem here is comparing null values. I think linq translates .Equals to " something = null" instead of "something is null". I don't know exactly why or if that's true, but it's what I could understand.

Answer (score 0):

One would end up using 'Equals' when comparing objects...or entities.

'==' is something you will always use when comparing just values...such as strings.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares references and `Equals()` is a virtual method that can behave however it is implemented.

Comment: Not necessarily. All Objects have a virtual Equals() method, whether they're IEquatable or not, and operators including == can be overloaded, so in fact both of these "behave however they are implemented". It's best practice to make them behave the same way unless you need both referential and structural equality comparisons (and in that case it's best practice to use IStructuralEquatable), however the compiler won't enforce any such best practices; anything that doesn't set the computer on fire is fine.

Comment: In the case described in the question it would seem I am correct though. `==` is referential and `Equals()` is structural.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, I think the difference in behavior when used in an NHibernate query is in the simple fact that they're different members of the object. The code in the OP never actually gets executed; it forms an expression tree, which is digested by the NH Linq provider into SQL. So it doesn't really matter how each one's implemented; what matters is what NH thinks it should do when given an expression node containing such a method.